# x86 ASM: TEST instruction with more than 1 bit

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm playing with the assembly TEST instruction but currently it confuses me.

AX=1110xB

When testing for a single bit,

if it is set then zf=0 (i.e. TEST AX,0001xB)

if it is unset then zf=1 (i.e. TEST AX,0010xB)

At this point everything is ok, but the problem (or my confusion) is when I want to test multiple bits in a single TEST instruction. If just one of the tested bits is set, then zf=0. For example:

AX=1110xB

TEST AX,0110xB -> zf=0 (both bits are set)

TEST AX,0011xB -> zf=0 (only 1 bit is set, but I asked for 2 bits)

TEST AX,1110xB -> zf=0 (the three bits are set)

The question is: How can I test for multiple bits and expect for a positive result (zf=0) only IF ALL THE TESTED BITS ARE "1"? For example like in C/C++ when you use the logical & to check for a mask of bits (10101101&00000101)... Or should I test one bit at once in assembly?

My program gives "negative" if the bit(s) are unset, but gives "positive" if at least 1 bit is set and not all the tested bits are 1.

I tried with two different debuggers and the result is the same.

Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 5):

You can't check for multiple non-zero bits with one instruction; as you noticed ZF is set depending on whether or not there are *any* non-zero bits in the result.

The usual method is

```
and  AX, mask        ; clear all the non-mask bits
cmp  AX, mask        ; check that all the mask bits *are* set
je  all_bits_set
```

(where `mask` is a register or the same immediate you use twice.)

If you need to do it without destroying AX, you need to copy the register somewhere else or save/restore the old value.

Comment: @kanito73: if that answered your question, you can mark the answer as accepted with the checkbox under the vote arrows.